# Why aren't I creating a widget with the information from the RTDB?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I don't understand why my code isn't creating the post. It should access the RTDB and put name1 and name2 into a new card that says "'name1' and 'name2'" but it only gives me a post that says "and". Here is the following code:

```
Post addPost() {
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    String name1;
    String name2;
    db
        .child('users')
        .child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snap.value;
      if (snap.value == null) {
        print("No data");
      }
      name1 = values['name1'];
      name2 = values['name2'];
    });
    return Post(
      name1: name1,
      name2: name2,
    );
  }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you run the code in a debugger, or add some `print` statements, you will see that your `return Post( name1: name1, name2: name2,);` runs before the `name1 = values['name1'];` ever executes.

That's because data is loaded from Firebase (and most cloud APIs) asynchronously, and your main code (the `return` statement) continues to execute while the data is loaded. Then when the data is available, the callback block is executed. But at that point, nobody will see the assignment to `name1` and `name2` anymore.

The solution is to return a `Future<Post>` instead of just `Post` and using `async` and `await`:

```
Future<Post> addPost() async {
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    String name1;
    String name2;
    var snap = await db
        .child('users')
        .child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .once();
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snap.value;
    if (snap.value == null) {
      print("No data");
    }
    name1 = values['name1'];
    name2 = values['name2'];
    return Post(
      name1: name1,
      name2: name2,
    );
}
```

Also see:

- the Flutter documentation on [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)